# How to get the name of the current song using Sonos API (SMAPI)

Tags: sonos

I'd like to get the name of the currently playing song using Sonos Music API.

Is there a way of getting the currently playing song name without subscribing and waiting for a callback (using [playbackMetadata](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/playback-metadata/))?

Ideally a simple GET Http request.

Thanks!

Comment: On this one, I've not found a way to find this information with a simple GET. I  see quick response times when subscribing, but I do still see strange 'jumping' where an old value is shown and then updates do to the lag.

Comment: We currently don't have such a command. I'll forward your implicit request along to the devs.

Comment: One workaround is to use UPnP GetPositionInfo request. It's fairly easy to do, but I was hoping that the Sonos API will support something like this.

Comment: @MattWelch what is the best way to be notified of any API additions or changes? Thank you!

Comment: @Flo we post updates on the blog, and will send out periodic platform updates via email, to the address with which you registered on the dev portal.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
curl "http://192.168.49.119:5005/zones" | jq '.[].coordinator.state.currentTrack.title'
```